# Find a way to have different local-storage object for same origin, using different context path

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I need to created two local-storage object based on my context path.
`example.com/v1` and `example.com/v2`.

```
localstorage.setItem("id", "v1"); // for example.com/v1
localstorage.setItem("id", "v2"); // for example.com/v2

localstorage.getItem("id"); // v2 final out put.
```

But as far as I know local-storage is based on origin and in the this case the origin is same i.e `example.com`, and there will be one local-storage object which will be over-written. Which some how I have to restrict.

```
localstorage.getItem("id"); // v1 for example.com/v1
localstorage.getItem("id"); // v2 for example.com/v2
```

Thanks for providing help, advice and suggestions.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier how to find a way to have 2 local-storage object based on the URL example.com/v1 and example.com/v2

Comment: Please rephrase the question as such and add code in which you attempt to create your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could name the `keyName` of the `Storage` item by the current path of the document.
So for example on `example.com/v1` the `keyName` would be `v1` and on `example.com/v2` it would be `v2`.

Down here I've made two functions which will set and get the values based on the current path of the page. So depending on what page you are it will get or set only the values of that page.

```
function storeItemByPath(value, path = location.pathname) {
    localStorage.setItem(path, value);
}
```

```
function getStoredItemByPath(path = location.pathname) {
    return localStorage.getItem(path);
}
```

```
storeItemByPath('hello');
let value = getStoredItemByPath(); // Returns 'hello' but only on this page.
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: This will help, but a work-around is need as localstorage for `V1` and `V2` should be different but using path as a key for these will create multiple storage object because the path will be like `V1/example-v1/id=2/newId=10` and `V1/example-v1/id=2/newId=10` so some how using regx i need to create keys as V1 and V2.

Comment: Your URL structure seems quite unorthodox. Why don't you try to use a query string in your URL, like so: `example.com/v1?id=2&newId=10`. That seems like the way to go.